# PHP While Loop In a While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

Trying to run a script to email users their individual schedules from my database.

The code should go like this...select all users from Table 1 where users want their weekly email.

Then take those user_ids and run a query to obtain the weekly schedules for each user from Table 2.

If the date in the Table 2 is less than or equal to 1 week from when the code is ran, and it does not equal today's date, then set the variable $email_content.

If the date in the Table 2 exceeds 1 week, then the code should know that it is done, and here is would like to go ahead and mail() the info gathered for that user and send only that info, to only that user, then continue on to the next user.

Where it says echo "break", it is essentially marking the separation between each users' schedule, but it is echoing about 20 times. This part will ideally become where I put the mail() function, so I can't have it execute the mail() function 20 times too.

I've tried a ton of different variations of this code, but can't seem to get it right. To summarize, I need to get info1 for user1, then mail info1 to user1, then move on to get info2 for user2, then mail info2 to user2, etc...

```
<?php

// GET USERS WHO WANT THEIR WEEKLY SCHEDULE EMAILED TO THEM (Table 1)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXXX WHERE weekly_email = 'Yes'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id .= "'" . $row['user_id'] . "', ";
}
$id = trim($id, ', ');

// GET THOSE USERS' SCHEDULES (Table 2)
$sql_email = "SELECT * FROM XXXXXXXX WHERE user_id IN ($id) ORDER BY user_id, date, start_time ASC";

$result_email = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_email);

while ($row_email = mysqli_fetch_array($result_email)) {
    $truck_name_email = $row_email['truck_name'];
    $location_name_email = $row_email['location_name'];
    $date_email = $row_email['date'];
    $address_email = $row_email['address'];
    $x = strtotime("7 days");

    $start_email = $row_email['start_time'];
    $end_email = $row_email['end_time'];

    if ($date_email <= date("m/d/Y l", $x)) {

        if ($date_email !== date("m/d/Y l")) {
            if (!empty($address_email)) {
                $address_email2 = explode(",", $row_email['address'], 2);
                $email_content = $date_email . substr($date_email, 11) . " - "
                    . $location_name_email . ", " . $address_email2[0] . ", "
                    . $start_email . "-" . $end_email . "<br/>";

                echo $email_content;
            } elseif (empty($address_email)) {
                $email_content .= $date_email . " - " . $location_name_email
                    . ", " . $start_email . "-" . $end_email . "<br/>";

                echo $email_content;
            }
        }
    }
    if ($date_email >= date("m/d/Y l", $x)) {
        echo "break";
        // break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for two queries. Just use a subquery. Where you have `IN($id)` say instead `IN(SELECT user_id FROM XXXXXX WHERE weekly_email = 'Yes)`

Comment: You are comparing two strings in your if-blocks when you want to be comparing timestamps instead. Is "Thursday" > "Sunday" for example?

Comment: Thank you @siride, I got rid of the first query in my code and updated the 2nd with your recommendation.

Comment: @Drakes the two strings are essentially "07/24/16 Sunday" < "07/31/Sunday". My code is getting all of the dates less than or equal to 7 days from now, my problem is taking all of those dates and emailing them to the user and then moving on to the next user in the database and repeating the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just saying that you should pay attention to potential SQL injection, escape any user-controllable strings before they get in the SQL statement. For example if `$row['user_id']` is a string then you must perform `mysqli_escape_string`

Seems like that you forgot something in your code:

```
    $x = strtotime("7 days");

    $start_email = $row_email['start_time'];
    $end_email = $row_email['end_time'];

    if ($date_email <= date("m/d/Y l", $x)) {

        if ($date_email !== date("m/d/Y l")) { // I think that you have a $x here?
            if (!empty($address_email)) {
                $address_email2 = explode(",", $row_email['address'], 2);
                $email_content = $date_email . substr($date_email, 11) . " - "
                    . $location_name_email . ", " . $address_email2[0] . ", "
                    . $start_email . "-" . $end_email . "<br/>";
```

Comment: A weekly Cron Job runs this script, and nothing is user-controlled. All information is already stored within the database, I'm just trying to extract info specific to certain users, and email it to them. $date_email !== date("m/d/Y l") is basically saying, as long as the date in the database, is not equal to today's date, then { run code }. $x essentially converts today's date (date("m/d/Y l")) into the date, 7 days from today. What I'm trying to do is get info for 1 user for 1 week then email that info to that user, and then move on to the next user, and so forth.

Comment: @Shane Sorry but maybe I didn't understand your problem clearly. If you have 20 users then you of course have to run mail() 20 times. If you have 20 messages then maybe you can merge different messages using the GROUP BY technique.

Comment: It's okay. Consider you and I are two users in this scenario. I just want to mail information related to me, to me, and information related to you, to you while a condition is met. Where the code says echo "break"; is where I would run mail(). My code is echoing "break" for every instance where a database entry is found, meaning that the mail() function would be ran for every instance where a database entry is found...which is too many. Sorry if that isn't a good explanation, it is kind of tricky to find the right words. I think I have an idea though...